# Ember computed properties output to page as plaintext

Tags: ember.js

My `ApplicationController` looks like this:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    test: function() {
        return 'test';
    }
});
```

When I try to use this computed property in my template as `{{test}}` the resulting html output is the function definition as text:

```
<script id="metamorph-8-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
function () {
    return 'test';
}
<script id="metamorph-8-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
```

I am probably missing something obvious, but I have no idea what that would be. Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a computed property you should declare it as one, e.g. add `.property()` at the end of your computed property function:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  test: function() {
    return 'test';
  }.property()
});
```

If the computed property depends on another property then you should declare on which like `.property('myProperty');` to get your `test` computed property re-execute whenever `myProperty` changes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I've read through the guides on computed properties a gazillion times and there are no examples where the property definition is empty. So I assumed that it only needed to be there if there were dependencies. Silly me.